# Arguments list syntax

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to understend construction like this:

```
  - (void)someMethodWithArgs:(type?) param, ...
{
        ???
}

[self someMethodWithArgs:arg1, arg2, arg3];
```

- How to get acces to arguments list?
- Should 'type' be a pointer, or it can be 'int', for example?

Comment: This should work: [Variable arguments in Objective-C methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1405/_index.html), and a nice tutorial here [Variable argument lists in Cocoa](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/variable-argument-lists-in-cocoa.html)

Comment: Could you post this as an answer, please? This is directly what I whant, so I need to "accept" your answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matt Gallagher provides a nice tutorial on Variable Arguments lists:

[Variable argument lists in Cocoa](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/variable-argument-lists-in-cocoa.html)

In Apple's docs there's also a short Technical Q&A QA1405 on this topic:

[Variable arguments in Objective-C methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1405/_index.html)

Answer (score 4):

The way Objective-C functions work.

**Declaration**

```
- (void) someMethodWithArgA:(type)paramName argB:(typeB)paramNameB
{
     // do something with paramName and paramNameB 

}
```

**Calling**

```
[self someMethodWithArgA:val argB:valB];
```

---

The C-equivalent would be :

```
void someMethodWithArgs(type paramName, typeB paramNameB)
{
     // do something with paramName and paramNameB    
}

someMethodWithArgs(val,valB);
```

---

And of course, as with C, variable types can be **anything** (why should they be just pointers?).

---

**A simple example :**

```
- (int)addNum:(int)a withNum:(int)b
{
      int c = a+b;
      return c;
}

int k = [self addNum:2 withNum:3];
// k = 5
```

---

### Reference

> The Objective-C model of object-oriented programming is based on
>   message passing to object instances. In Objective-C one does not
>   simply call a method; one sends a **message**.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Messages

---

### **UPDATE**

**Implementing method with variable number of arguments**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface NSMutableArray (variadicMethodExample)

- (void) appendObjects:(id) firstObject, ...; // This method takes a nil-terminated list of objects.

@end

@implementation NSMutableArray (variadicMethodExample)

- (void) appendObjects:(id) firstObject, ...
{
     id eachObject;
     va_list argumentList;
     if (firstObject) // The first argument isn't part of the varargs list,
     {                                   // so we'll handle it separately.
          [self addObject: firstObject];
          va_start(argumentList, firstObject); 
          // Start scanning for arguments after firstObject.

          // As many times as we can get an argument of type "id"
          while (eachObject = va_arg(argumentList, id)) 
                 [self addObject: eachObject]; 

          va_end(argumentList);
     }
}

@end
```

From : http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1405/_index.html

Comment: Tnx for response, but You didn't understand my question correctly: I need to implement a variable number of method's arguments. Comment from rokjarc to my questions links to right docs.

Comment: @SentineL Sorry, my bad; just updated my original answer. :-)

Answer (score 4):

In ObjC argument list syntax originates C argument list syntax.

```
- (void) appendObjects:(id) firstObject, ...
{
id eachObject;
va_list argumentList;
va_start(argumentList, firstObject); // Start scanning for arguments after firstObject.
while (eachObject = va_arg(argumentList, id)) // As many times as we can get an argument of type "id"
  [self addObject: eachObject]; // that isn't nil, add it to self's contents.
va_end(argumentList);
}
```

You can find more information from here: [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1405/_index.html)

Update: ooops, i'm a little late :)